# Magento catalog - Duplicate category using static block

Tags: php, magento

In the web-shop i'm creating we want the customers to see the category new as they are landing in the shop.

Our configuration in the whole catalog is an layout of 4 items next to each other, like below:

four items in one row

*sorry i am not yet allowed to post pictures :(

I've made an static block in Magento using the following code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="7" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

But when i call this block at the place I wan't it to display, it does not use the correct layout:

3 items in one row, two rows

*sorry i am not yet allowed to post pictures :(

It only put's 3 items next to each otter. I've already tried tweaking the css but that's not the problem. The page code shows that it is put in another row:

```
<ul class="products-grid first odd"> (the first row)
<ul class="products-grid last even"> (the second row)
```

My guess is that when i call the block it sets the display to 3 items a row, but i can't figure out where that configuration is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way 1:
for you to use modificated template catalog/product/list.phtml

Create new template from this one and call it list-home.phtml and where you have grid mode view you must have something like this:

```
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
```

replace this with

```
<?php $_columnCount = 4; ?>
```

Way 2: Add this block via layout or custom layout in admin area and add to it params like:

```
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
```

Sorry - second way would not work via static block - you can add this w/o static block directly in Layout Update XML in CMS home page, also I don't understand for what you using static block for this if you can add this code for block directly in CMS Page content too

Comment: Thnx! i used way one and it is now the same as the original. I went with an static block because of the way the store was build. There is no real template so the savest way in my opinion was to use a static block.